# Why does the result of mysqli_query return an object with its fields set to null?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have looked for information about the following both here and on the php website but I can't quite understand the problem.

I will expose my doubt step by step.

I want to obtain the id of the user whose email is the one indicated in the `$email` variable

```
$result = execute_db("SELECT id FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email'");
```

I call the function execute_db that will connect to my database and execute the query

```
function execute_db($query) {
    $connection = db_connect();

    $result = mysqli_query ($connection, $query);

    error_log("Debug execute_db::" .json_encode($result));
    error_log("Debug execute_db:: query: " .$query);
}
```

The log file shows the following:

```
Debug execute_db::{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
Debug execute_db:: query: SELECT id, usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email = 'xxx@xxx.com'
```

If I enter an email that is in the database, I get the data:

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

```
{"id":"xx"}
```

Why does the $result variable return an object with its fields null (current_field, num_rows...) if it has "fetched" 1 record?

If I run this it won't do what I expect:

```
if (!$result || !$result->num_rows) {
    throw new Exception(gettext("No existe una cuenta asociada a ese correo"));
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug in mysqli](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6587). You can't stringify the mysqli object like this. The properties aren't NULL, but `json_encode` can't access them internally.